# How do I use req.flash() with nunjucks?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, nunjucks, connect-flash

I am using connect-flash to pass the flash message. In my controller, I am using the following code `if (!req.user) {
        req.flash("error_msg", "User not found !!");
        return res.redirect(307, '/');
      }`

In my view, I tried

> {{ error_message }}
>
> {{ req.flash('error_message') }}
>
> {{ req.flash.get('error_message') }}

But none of it works. What's the current syntax to parse the flash message in nunjucks ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using express js and nunjucks as template this is what I have done

in app.js

```js
const flash = require('express-flash');
app.use(flash());
```

in Routes/controller code

```js
try {
        await User.deleteOne({_id:req.params._id}).exec()   
        req.flash("success_msg", "User deleted");           
        return res.redirect('/admin/users') 
}
```

in Layout or view file

```js
 {% if messages.success_msg  %}
          <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            {{ messages.success_msg }}
          </div>
        {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to install "express-flash" and put below code in app.js

app.js

```
const flash = require('express-flash');
```

In Your Controller put below code when you want to pass message

```
req.flash('error_msg', "User not found !!");
        return res.redirect(307, '/');
```

Put below code in your view file where you want to display message

```
<% if (typeof messages.error_msg !='undefined') { %>
        <p class="error"><%= messages.error_msg %></p>
    <% } %>
```

Comment: Please install mentioned plugin : "npm install express-flash"

Comment: Is it relevant if I am not using express ? I am using sailsjs framework !!

Comment: this is for express js

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing the same problem you can access the variable using `{{ req.session.flash.error_msg }}`

Answer (score 0):

With `connect-flash` package, you cannot directly use `req.flash` in template engine. You need to add a middleware that adds the flash message to the `res.locals` which can be accessed in template rendering.

Here is a short code snippet.

```js
// this part should be before all the request resolver.
// adding flash function to response locals
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
 res.locals.flash = (arg) => { return req.flash(arg) };
 next();
});

// request resolver
app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
 req.flash("info","show me");
 res.render("index.njk",{});
});

app.listen(8080,()=>{...})
```

In nunjucks file:

```
<h3>{{ flash("info") }}</h3>
```